# This is for jQuery Mobile. Unable to disable my input button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to disable an input submit button.

the problem is,

1. with my below code the button only seems to disable when the page is refreshed.
2. i tried using `$(this).atrr('refresh');` so once the button has been disabled it should refresh it so it visually appears to be disabled

any advise would be much appreciated

**html**

```
<input class="submit button-primary btn large send submit_wide" id="wp-submit" name="up_submit" tabindex="250" type="submit" value="test" />
```

**jquery mobile code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var clicked = false;

        $('#wp-submit').click(function() {
            if(clicked === false) {
                $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
                // $(this).atrr('refresh');
                clicked = true;
            } 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: try $(this).prop instead of $(this).attr.  here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2v6wprLw/1/

Comment: @sushil, i tried your suggestion but the same problem still occurs. the disabled function works, but its only visually displayed as disabled when i refresh the page

Comment: When are you re-enabling the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works on JSFiddle :[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ac820utf/). 
Maybe you can try the JQueryMobile function **.button('disable')** :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var clicked = false;

        $('#wp-submit').click(function() {
            if(clicked === false) {
                $(this).button('disable');  
               // $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
                clicked = true;
            } 
        });
    });
```

Looks like refresh is a normal thing to do (From [JQueryMobile website](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/buttons/buttons-methods.html)):

> If you manipulate a form button via JavaScript, you must call the refresh method on it to update the visual styling.

```
$('[type="submit"]').button('refresh');
```

Comment: Charle Follet, thank you soo much!!!. i also realised that for my html my input type read as  `type="submit"` rather than  `type="button"` but with your code it all works perfect well